# How can I accept Json object from post request?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to receive a post from a server in the format:

```
{
    "event_type": "test",
    "event_info": {
        "key": "value",
        "more unknown key":"Value pairs"...
    }
}
```

Then serialize it into a sqlite db.

I'm not finding a good way to do this. It doesn't like {} I get returned "Not a valid string." I haven't found a good way to accept the json object. I could just store the json as a string but I can't figure out how to convert it to a string either.

I have views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Subscription
from .Serializers import SubscriptionSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.http import HttpResponse

class SubscriptionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Subscription.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    serializer_class = SubscriptionSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'delete']
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Subscription(models.Model):
    event_type = models.TextField(default='Failed to set')
    event_info = models.TextField(default='Failed to set')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Subscription

class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = ('id', 'event_type', 'event_info')
```

Comment: Can you show how do you send your request to the server?

Comment: I'm not sending anything. I'm trying to receive a POST from another server.

Comment: that server should send request in the form that you accept

Comment: Perfect world I would agree, however, that server is out of my control and I need to accept the payload in the format that it sends it to me.

Comment: your whole API is built only for that server or it might be consumed by other clients?

Comment: It is only built for that server.

Comment: Try  to use `APIView`, with this CBV you have more flexibility

Comment: I'll try that out.

Comment: Also you may need to create another model for EventInfo (I see that you have a nested dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested serializer:

```
class KeySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    key = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)


class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    event_type = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    event_info = KeySerializer()
```

EventSerializer should be able to parse/validate json you posted.

Comment: Is there a way KeySerializer will work if I don't know every key and the keys maybe different based on what is passed in event_type?